# Nagasena/OpenExi: encoding xml with &lt; in attribute

Tags: java, c#, xml, exi, openexi

I have implemented Nagasena encoder in C#:

```
 public byte[] encodeEXI(byte[] inBytes)
    {
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(inBytes);
        try
        {
            Transmogrifier transmogrifier = new Transmogrifier();
            GrammarCache grammarCache = new GrammarCache((EXISchema)null, GrammarOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
            transmogrifier.setGrammarCache(grammarCache, (SchemaId)null);
            transmogrifier.OutputStream = outStream;
            transmogrifier.AlignmentType = AlignmentType.compress;
            transmogrifier.PreserveWhitespaces = false;
            transmogrifier.PreserveLexicalValues = false;
            transmogrifier.DeflateLevel = 1;
            transmogrifier.ResolveExternalGeneralEntities = false;


            Org.System.Xml.Sax.InputSource<Stream> iS = new Org.System.Xml.Sax.InputSource<Stream>(inStream);
            transmogrifier.encode(iS);

            outStream.Position = 0;
            last = outStream.ToArray();
            return outStream.ToArray();
        }
        catch (TransmogrifierException tex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in OpenExi_Library: " + tex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            outStream.Close();
            inStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

and i have problem with encoding simple and valid xml witch contains <> or `&lt;&gt;`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<BPN>
  <Booo id="6001&lt;" />
  <PoooPoo id="2600" />
  <UserName>tomas</UserName>
  <VooId>MYID</VooId>
  <Text>&lt;</Text>
</BPN>
```

it just end with TransmogrifierException: Nagasena.Sax.TransmogrifierException: End of document is not expected.

I am using c# implementation, so i tested problem in java implementation - there it is working good.
So i tried to change some options, but nothing helped.

When i replace `<Text>&lt;</Text>` with `<Text><![CDATA[<]]></Text>` and from `<Booo id="6001&lt;" />` i removed `&lt;` - `<Booo id="6001" />`, encoding was successfull. But in attribute there is no possibillity of using cdata and when it contains <> or `&lt;&gt;` it ends up with error.

I'm going to debug nagasena library, but if someone has some usefull advices, i would be gratefull.

thx

Comment: after debug some nagasena code... i received internal SaxException: {"reference to externally declared entity \"lt\" when document is declared standalone"}, so i changed property standalone to no, and it is working, but i dont understand why...

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to the use of AElfred XML parser within Nagasena.
Latest nagasena uses Microsoft XML parser instead, and should no longer exhibit this problem.